In “AS an organization WE” is WE considered a personal pronoun?
I am doing a student activity called (MUN) and one of the rules is having to refrain from using personal pronouns. Now since Arabic is my native language, this makes speaking extremely hard as I constantly have to make sure I don’t use any personal pronouns. Arabic heavily uses personal pronouns so speaking in English without personal pronouns is extremely hard for me.
I asked chatGPT if in “As organizations we”, “WE” is considered a personal pronoun or not. And it said in this context WE isn't considered a personal pronoun, but I am not too sure of its answer since LLMs like chatGPT hallucinate A LOT in their responses.
So in “As organizations WE” is the WE here a personal pronoun or not?

"We" is a personal pronoun.

How can you possibly write English without using personal pronouns? Why is somebody imposing this restriction on you?

@DJClayworth It is probably a grammar exercise aimed at making the students more aware of the connection between the personal pronouns and their referents.

Then I'd move to “As an organization, ABC does ..." or "the purpose of ABC is to..."

Any dictionary will label we as a pronoun as it stands for a group of people including I:

I and the rest of a group that includes me : you and I : you and I and another or others : I and another or others not including you  —used as pronoun of the first person plural (M-W)

If you are not allowed to use personal pronouns, I suggest you use the name of the actual organization you are speaking about:

As an organization, (the) XXX ...

As for chatGPT, it may help sometimes to find a direction to research further, but it is rarely able to give exact accurate answers, and in fact it sometimes apologises for that or moderates its claim to the accuracy of the answer it provides. Never take a chatGPT answer as the ultimate truth.
